# Algorithmic error in a piece of Python code - I can not do what I have to do

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of data:

[18.0, 18.0, 28.35, 81.26, 1.99, 1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 14.8, 1.78, 5.79, 21.18, 2.54, 3.0, 1.69, 8.11, 1.57, 1.31, 11.19, 8.14, 1.42, 4.72]

I want whenever two of these numbers have a value less than 2, the third number is stored in another list. For example, if the first two numbers are less than 2; The third number enters the list and when the third and fourth numbers are below 2, the fifth number is also in the list.
But the problem is that if several consecutive coefficients are less than 2, the program will have trouble recognizing the correct coefficients.
My code is:

```
for listItrator in listOfCoefficients_float:
    if listItrator < lowCoefficientsCounter: #lowCoefficientsCounter: Is equal to 2 as assumed
        wait = wait + 1
        if wait == wait2: #wait2: This variable is entered by the user, which according to the pattern described at the beginning of the problem, is equal to 2 here
            trimmedCofficientsFiller = listOfCoefficients_float.index(listItrator)
            finalOutputCofficients_float.append(float(listOfCoefficients_float[trimmedCofficientsFiller + 1])) #Save the next coefficient in the list
            wait = 0
    elif listItrator >= lowCoefficientsCounter:
        wait = 0
```

The output list is:
[1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.19]

While my desired output is:
[1.4, 1.4, 14.8, 11.19]

Comment: What do you think ``if wait == wait:`` checks for?

Comment: The code shown outputs ``[1.3, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 5.79, 8.11, 1.31, 11.19, 4.72]`` for me, not ``[1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.19]``.

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet? What were your insights?

Comment: I made a mistake. These two variables `wait == wait` are different
I am correcting now ...

Comment: I also tried debugging with VS code, but could not do it step by step as I debugged C # in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In a problem like this, as you also noticed, extra care must be taken in order not to mess up your comparisons and generally the indexes you are working with. A working solution is shown below:

```
res = []
for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])):
    if x < 2.0 and y < 2.0:
        res.append(lst[2+2*i])
print(res)  # [1.4, 1.4, 14.8, 11.19]
```

It also comes in list-comprehension if you want to save some bytes:

```
res = [lst[2*i] for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]), 1) if max(x,y)<2.0]
```

In both cases, `lst` is your original list.

I am quite confident that you can understand it, but if not, let me know and I will add some further explanations.

Note that, as @MisterMiyagi says, instead of `enumerat`ing and calculating the indexes yourself, you can squeeze some extra juice from the `zip` like so:

```
res = [z for (x,y,z) in zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2], lst[2::2]) if max(x,y)<2.0]
```

Comment: Instead of computing the position of the result element, you can also just add it to ``zip``. ``zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2], lst[2::2])`` iterates over the triplets.

Comment: Very true; that's even more elegant. I added it to the answer.

Comment: I did not understand exactly what this part of the code does:
lst [:: 2], lst [1 :: 2]
Or what is the purpose of lst [2 + 2 * i] (on what basis are the numbers chosen?

Because even now the problem with the code output is that it shows the last number below 2, not just the third of the three combinations that the first two have a coefficient of less than 2.

Comment: The first two (`lst[::2]` and `lst[1::2]`) are examples of python's list slicing notation. They help us in this case get the elements we need for the comparisons from the list. The last one `lst[2+2*i]` is simply list indexing. The index used is based on the `i` that the `enumerate` produces. It has been calcutated like that to return the correct element every time the comparison is successful.

Comment: Yes, yes, I understand. Thank you very much for your guidance
I think I was confused because the indexes you wrote were not useful for my program (of course you did not see all my code and it is normal that the indexes are not accurate)
But for the explanations I gave, the following indexes made me work:
`
res = []
for i, (x,y) in enumerate(zip(listOfCoefficients_float[0::1], listOfCoefficients_float[1::1])):
    print(x , y)
    if x < 2.0 and y < 2.0:
        print("*listOfCoefficients", listOfCoefficients_float[2+i])
        res.append(listOfCoefficients_float[2+i])
`

Answer (score 1):

On line

```
            trimmedCofficientsFiller = listOfCoefficients_float.index(listItrator)
```

You are looking for the first number that satisfies the index, and not the second, third, etc. instances. `1.4` shows up multiple times, so your program always picks out the first `1.4`instance. Consider iterating through the list with indices, instead (e.g. `for n in range(0,len(listOfCoefficients_float))`)

Comment: I added this value in the next code line. Where I use the append() method